# Jenkins - How can I lock template Job configurations for normal users but provide them to be copied?

Tags: permissions, jenkins, template

I setting up a Jenkins-Server for our Company.

To make things easy for our developers, I created 2 template Jobs with the usual required configurations. So when users creat new jobs they can use `Copy from` to copy the configuration of the templates instead of everytime setting all up from scratch.

But now I would like to hide those templates for normal users and only allow them to copy the configuration or at least give only my admin account the permission to make changes to the configuration of the templates.

Actually I thought I could use the project-based security Plugin for that, but ofcourse if I enable and configure project-based security for the template job, this settings will also be copied to the new created Job.

**Is there some way this can be done?**

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but you *should* be able to do this by revoking the "configure job" permission for normal users while keeping their "create job" permissions.  I'm not totally sure if this accomplishes exactly what you want, but I believe this will allow users to create jobs from templates but not edit the configuration of the created job.

If that doesn't work, ultimately, you're going to have to revoke the create and configure jobs permissions for normal users.  One approach that will allow users to still create jobs in this scenario would be to create a parameterized metajob that creates new jobs by copying from the golden template.  This job would take at least one parameter (the name of the job to be created).